# Tascam 4x4 usb interface only playing from 2 mics with 4 mics plugged in

Tags: mixer, usb, interface

I plugged this tascam usb interface us 4x4 into my windows 10 machine and only the first 2 channels are playing audio. I have tried on a Windows and Mac machine and the same thing happens. What's unusual though is that when I shut down my computer and leave the USB cable plugged in I can hear audio from all 4 mics into my headphones.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUp11.jpg)

Comment: This is not a question, it's an observation. If you have a question, please feel free to ask it, but it sounds like you need to review the operating instructions for your interface first.